# Ruby Soundcloud Gem: Cannot Test Uploaded File

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, capybara, soundcloud

Haven't seen much on testing for the soundcloud gem.  Most everything has been splendid - however I found that uploading files to SoundCloud through my specs is a bit tricky.

Here's the problem:

spec:

```
file = "#{Rails.root}/spec/factories/files/sample.mp3"
title = "From the test suite"
track = @client.post('/tracks', track: {title: title, asset_data: File.new(file)})
```

Whether or not I use

```
File.new
```

or

```
File.expand_path
```

the error is the same: **NoMethodError:
       undefined method `map' for #String:0x007fa1ce8425c0**

The successful code in the controller is:

```
file = params["soundcloud_file"]
title = params["title"]
track = client.post('/tracks', track: {
  title: title
  asset_data: File.new(file.tempfile, 'rb')
  })
```

Now I understand that params["soundcloud_file"] is an ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile, so that's what I've been attempting to work with for the past hour or so with no luck.

I'm open to any way to successfully test an upload.

Comment: An update.  After finding that the test could not pass, even after merely triggering a controller action that POSTed a track fetched by the controller, I knew something fishy was up.  

So I uninstalled a bunch of testing gems I was trying out but were not integral: VCR, Webmock, Binding of Caller, and Capybara-Mechanize.  I'm leaning toward Binding of Caller as the culprit... will let you know if I find out specifically what the deal was.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was with the 'webmock' gem. Even using the required version for VCR (<1.10.0) it throws:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `map' for <#String: ... >
```

Replacing with the 'fakeweb' gem corrects the error.